# allow unit date range selection for SfDateRangePicker on multiRange mode

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

I'm trying to use the SfDateRangePicker with selectionMode setted to DateRangePickerSelectionMode.multiRange and be able to select a interval that starts and ends on the same day (double tap on same day), and also other arbitrary intervals.

The problem is that when I select the startDate and endDate on the same day it ignores the endDate and creates a interval with the next differnt day tapped.

I tried to change the _datePickerController.selectedRanges, with setting the callback param "onSelectionChanged"

```
onSelectionChanged: (DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args){
                PickerDateRange? lastValue = args.value?.last;
                if (lastValue != null && lastValue.startDate == lastValue.endDate){
                  _lastPickerDate = lastValue;
                }
                else if (_lastPickerDate != null){
                  final a = _datePickerController.selectedRanges!.last;
                  _datePickerController.selectedRanges!.remove(a);
                  _datePickerController.selectedRanges?.add(_lastPickerDate!);
                  _datePickerController.selectedRanges?.add(PickerDateRange(a.endDate, null));
                  _lastPickerDate = null;
                }
              }
```

[image: double tapped day before]

[image: double tapped day after]

but it still dont work. I also tried the same idea with an outside button that change the selectedRanges:

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
              _datePickerController.selectedRanges = [
                PickerDateRange(DateTime.now(), DateTime.now()),
                PickerDateRange(DateTime(2023,10,13), null),

                ];

            }, child: Text("change"))
```

[image: before button]

[image: after button and second tap]

It worked, but even with that clue I culdnt find a solution. Can someone help me ?